# Mahabharata and its pre-divisions

Tags: mahabharata, resource

I know that the present Mahabharata is of 1,00,000 verses. Is there any site where I can read the Bharata (24,000 verses)?

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan I also wanted a site where I can read Bharata. So it's not an exact duplicate of the 8000 verses question which you pointed out.

Comment: If you remove the part about the 8800-verse Jaya and just focus on the 24,000 verse Bharata, then it wouldn't be a duplicate anymore and I'd be happy to reopen it.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan Done.

Comment: OK, I reopened it.